# Haskell - Writing a function that searches and counts in Trie structure

Tags: haskell

This is how the Trie data structure is declared in my code:

```
data Trie = MakeTrie Char [Trie]
```

Now I have to write a function called countChar that receives a Trie and a target value (of Char type) and counts how many times target value appears in the Trie.

This is the code I've written:

```
countChar :: Trie -> Char -> Integer
countChar (MakeTrie root []) target 
    | root == target = 1
    | otherwise = 0
countChar (MakeTrie root children) target 
    | root == target = 1 + ...
    | otherwise = 0 + ...
```

Originally I wanted to do something that maps the function like this:

```
...otherwise = 0 + foldr1 (+) (map count children target)
where
count = countChar t c
```

But I think that doesn't work properly and now I'm more or less out of ideas of what to do in order to make the function work.

Comment: If you can change your signature to `countChar :: Char -> Trie -> Integer` you could do `sum(map (countChar target) children))`

Comment: @moondaisy thanks, I will try out your suggestion

Comment: @moondaisy Hmm...it doesn't compile correctly.  Is this what you were suggesting? countChar (MakeTrie root children) target = sum(map (countChar target) children)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the signature of your method to `countChar :: Char -> Trie -> Integer` then you can do this:

```
countChar :: Char -> Trie -> Integer
countChar target (MakeTrie root children) 
    | root == target = (1 + sum(map (countChar target) children))
    | otherwise = (0 +sum(map (countChar target) children))
```

This way you can use `map` on the list of `Trie`.

For example given `countChar 'A' (MakeTrie 'A' [MakeTrie 'B' [MakeTrie 'A' [] ], MakeTrie 'C' []])` it will return 2.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more "fun" way to define `Trie` is

```
type Trie = Cofree [] Char
```

This gives us a `Foldable` instance for free, since `[]` is `Foldable`. We could have also just added a `deriving Foldable` to the data decl for `Trie`.

This means we can do:

```
countChar :: (Eq a,Num n,Foldable t) => a -> t a -> n
countChar c = foldr (\c' a -> if c == c' then a + 1 else a) 0
```

That type signature can be specialized to just `Char -> Trie -> Integer` if you want. (With `a ~ Char`, `t ~ Cofree []`, `n ~ Integer`)

You could also implement this with `Sum`:

```
countChar :: (Eq a,Num n,Foldable t) => a -> t a -> n
countChar c = getSum . foldMap (\c' -> if c == c' then Sum 1 else Sum 0)
```

Moral of the story: Utilize typeclasses and other existing mechanisms to sidestep boilerplate and generalize your code.

Comment: Great answer, although it's probably more advanced than what we're expected to know for Haskell types haha.